# Natbib citation error

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib

One of my citations is breaking my document. If I build it with the citation uncalled in the document and a fresh .bbl file, the document builds fine. If I try and call the citation, it breaks the build process and even if I remove the citation, I have to rebuild the .bbl file for a proper build.

Here is the citation, its quite small and simple but something is happening that I can't seem to fix.

```
@misc{Perez1,
author = {Perez, Hernain David},
booktitle = {CSCMP's Supply Chain Quarterly},
pages = {4},
title = {{Supply Chain Strategies: Which one hits the mark?}},
url = {http://www.supplychainquarterly.com/print/­supply­chain­strategies­which­one­hits­the­mark},
year = {2013}
}
```

I should state that I'm importing my .bib file from Mendeley and haven't had a problem with any other citation. I've move the citation to the first entry on the bib file.

I'm calling the citation with `\citet{Perez1}` and my master document is using `\usepackage[round]{natbib}`. The error I'm receiving is an Undefined control sequence.\Generic Error, not exactly helpful.

MWE:

```
 \usepackage[round]{natbib}
 \begin{document}
 Test citation \citep{Perez1}.
 \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
 \bibliography{Skripsie}
 \end{document}
```

> \@outlinefile=\write3 Package natbib Warning: Citation `Perez1' on
>   page 1 undefined on input line 15.
>   (C:\Users\reece\Documents\Engineering\Skripsie\Test.bbl [1
>   {C:/Users/reece/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}] !
>   Undefined control sequence. \GenericError ... 4 \errhelp \@err@ ...
>   l.12 ...­strategies­which­one­hits­the­mark} . The control sequence at
>   the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If
>   you have misspelled it (e.g.,`\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
>   spelling (e.g.,`I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget
>   about whatever was undefined.

Comment: In my experiment I get no error; the output is slightly better if you add `\usepackage{url}`, however.

Comment: Make a *complete* example, starting with `\documentclass`. And test it in some empty folder along with a small bib containing only the bib entry, to ensure that one can reproduce the error with this example.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the feedback. There was a problem with the URL. I just removed the entire URL from the citation and all went well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with the `url` field (I suppose direcly copied on the web), which probably had some invisible character in it. I retyped the url, changed the category from `@misc` to `@article` since it comes from a journal on line, loaded the `url` package to break long urls at the end of line.

I also propose to use `bblatex` with option `natbib` (it emulates the `\citet` and `citep` commands from `natbib`) and `style=authoryear`. The advantage, with `backend=biber` is you can input accented letters directly on the keyboard, since biber understands `utf8`.

I corrected the url, which wasn't exact, and the author's first name, which precisely has an accented letter.

*Code with natbib + bibtex:*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{url}

 \begin{document}

\citet{Perez1}.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{Skripsie}
```

*.bib file for bibtex*

```
@article{Perez1,
author = {Perez, Hern\'{a}in David},
journal = {CSCMP's Supply Chain Quarterly},
pages = {4},
title = {{Supply Chain Strategies: Which one hits the mark?}},
url = {{http://www.supplychainquarterly.com/print/20130306-supply-chain-strategies-which-one-hits-the-mark/}},
year = {2013},
}
```

[image]

Code with biblatex + biber:*

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[english = british]{csquotes}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[natbib, style=authoryear, backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Skripsie1.bib}

 \begin{document}

 A citation: \citet{Perez1}
\printbibliography

 \end{document} 

\end{document}
```

*.bib file for biber;*

```
@article{Perez1,
author = {Perez, Hernán David},
journal = {CSCMP's Supply Chain Quarterly},
pages = {4},
title = {Supply Chain Strategies: Which one hits the mark?},
url = {http://www.supplychainquarterly.com/print/20130306-supply-chain-strategies-which-one-hits-the-mark/},
year = {2013},
}
```

[image]